# Zebra label Printer InvalidPrinterException in mvc 4 webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, printing

I get "InvalidPrinterException" when i run the below code to print to a zebra label printer via an asp.net mvc web application. The inner message says 'No printers are installed'. However the printer is installed and is set as default printer too. I also printed an empty notepad label and the printer successfully printed it for me.

Please Help!

```
private void PrintZebra()
        {

                            foreach (string c in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
                        {
                                 if (c.Contains("ZPL")){

                                    var pageSetngs = new PageSettings();
                                    pageSetngs.Margins = new Margins(0,0,0,0);
                                    var prtrSetngs = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
                                    prtrSetngs.PrinterName = c;
                                    var pd = new PrintDocument();
                                    pd.PrinterSettings = prtrSetngs;
                                    pd.DocumentName = "test";
                                    pd.OriginAtMargins = false;
                                    pd.DefaultPageSettings = pageSetngs;
                                    pd.PrintPage += (sender, args) =>
                                    {
                                         System.Drawing.Font printFont = new System.Drawing.Font("3 of 9 Barcode", 17);
                                         System.Drawing.Font printFont2 = new System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
                                         SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
                                         args.Graphics.DrawString("*AAAAAAFFF*",printFont,br,10,65);
                                         args.Graphics.DrawString("*AAAAAAFFF*",printFont2,br,10,85);
                                    };
                                    pd.Print();

                         }
                  }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the printer is plugged into the client PC running the web browser and that the driver is intalled there.

The C# code is running on the server side and has no visibility of the printers installed on the client, therefore you're getting the invalid printer exception when you try to print to it.

If the printer is installed as a printer on the server then the account which the app pool is running under doesn't have access to the printer.

In this scenario you will need to create a server / domain service account to run your app under and make sure it has access rights to see the printer installed on the server.

The best way to handle this is to generate the label server side and push it to the client as a file that can then be viewed and printed. For example generate a PDF of the label and then stream it to the client for printing using the drivers installed on the client.

The blog link below shows you how to generate a PDF label using itextsharp plugin.

http://zootfroot.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/using-itextsharp-to-generate-avery.html

Comment: This is not quite a "link only answer" but it's close. Please consider adding the steps/relevant information from the linked page to your answer. StackOverflow tries to keep complete answers on the site itself and not to rely on third party sites that can be subject to "link rot".